# Route of Entity/Object from my model different from route.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model named **CalendarEntry** in my app, it's supposed to keep the data of an entry's blog.

The CalendarEntry is in an admin role, so the routes are like this:

```
/admins/calendar_entries
```

and my **route.rb** is this:

```
namespace :admins do
  resources :calendar_entries
end
```

but somehow, when I call the **entity** in my controller with this code:

```
@entry = CalendarEntry.new(params[:calendar_entries])
```

I get an **error** of routes that says:

> ```
> undefined method `calendar_entries_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fdc6adfe4d8>:0x007fdc6f70aeb0>
> ```

It's not supposed that if I have the CalendarEntry inside a namespace of admins I get the route of:

```
admins_calendar_entries_path
```

**??**

That's my big deal that the routes are okay, but my entity somehow get's another route different from the route.rb, anyone knows why? or if maybe I have to specify the route of CalendarEntry besides of routes.rb? Or what's the correct path?

I appreciate every response!

> Update July/16 - 3:18pm

My complete code of my controller is:

```
module Admins
  # Class for Entries
  class CalendarEntriesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_admin!

    def index; end

    def new
      @entry = CalendarEntry.new(params[:calendar_entries])
    end
  end
end
```

And my complete **routes** are:

```
  admins_calendar_entries  GET    /admins/calendar_entries(.:format)          admins/calendar_entries#index
                           POST   /admins/calendar_entries(.:format)          admins/calendar_entries#create
 new_admins_calendar_entry GET    /admins/calendar_entries/new(.:format)      admins/calendar_entries#new
edit_admins_calendar_entry GET    /admins/calendar_entries/:id/edit(.:format) admins/calendar_entries#edit
     admins_calendar_entry GET    /admins/calendar_entries/:id(.:format)      admins/calendar_entries#show
                           PATCH  /admins/calendar_entries/:id(.:format)      admins/calendar_entries#update
                           PUT    /admins/calendar_entries/:id(.:format)      admins/calendar_entries#update
                           DELETE /admins/calendar_entries/:id(.:format)      admins/calendar_entries#destroy
```

Comment: Did you also change your controller to be `Admins::CalendarEntriesController` ? How about entering `rake routes` in your console? What is written? Could you post it as well? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have my controller with the module in Admins, I update the rake routes @TiagoFarias

Comment: did you put your controller file inside a folder "admins" under the controllers folder? You should have app/controllers/admins/calendar_entries_controller.rb

Comment: Yes, I also did that! @TiagoFarias

Comment: I'm sure the problem is not happening exactly on the line you just described. That line is probably being executed. But right after the action `new` finishes, your controller tries to render the view in `/views/admins/calendar_entries/new.html.erb`. Take a look if there is such a path in your view as well. Also verify if the view is in the folder described above.

Comment: Yes, I also check the view and everything is correct, I actually have a simple form in my view, like this: `simple_form_for @entry`, but I'm sure it has nothing with the view because in my view I only take the variable described in the controller.

Comment: Oh, ok. You see, you probably have to tell the simple_form_for helper that you are using a namespace. Like: `simple_form_for [:admins, @entry]`

Comment: Gosshhh, I never thought it was that!, thanks so much men, I was so obsessed with the controller that I never think about the form, it helps me to solve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved in the comments, it turns out that my error it was caused by my view, I had a simple form like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @entry do |f| %>
  # Inputs fields
<% end %>
```

But the thing was that I had to specify the namespace that I'm calling it, so I did that with this:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admins, @entry] do |f| %>
  # Inputs fields
<% end %>
```

*Moral of a fable:* Not everything is what it seems